# Bash brace expansion of {a..Z}

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In `bash`, you can do cool brace expansions like this:

```
$ echo {a..z}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Experimenting around with this, I decided to try some weird things:

```
$ echo {a..Z}
a ` _ ^ ]  [ Z
```

Where did this sequence come from?

Comment: This was answered in another forum: [Unusual characters in Brace expansion of characters in bash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/621349/unusual-characters-in-brace-expansion-of-characters-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation, it looks like this came from reading the ASCII table backwards from `a` to `Z`.